# How can I cover the entire iPhone screen with the keyboard being show?

Tags: objective-c

Imagine a simple translucent mask that I'd like to cover the whole iphone screen:

```
  UIView *maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
   maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   maskView.alpha = 0.0f;
   maskView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:maskView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:.7 delay:.5f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                     maskView.alpha = .3f;

    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

However, the screen is displaying the keyboard ( I have made a textfiled in the view a first responder).

How can I cover the keyboard with my maskView?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple doesn't like you doing that sort of thing. Have you considered just dismissing the keyboard when you display your mask view?

Comment: I could dismiss the keyboard, but the screen is designed to have the keyboard visible. If its not there, I have a big gap in the interface.

Comment: Hopefully you find a solution that easier than rolling your own keyboard. Though that is always an option.

Comment: I could just create an image of the keyboard I suppose..